# How to export to 500px from Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, publishing, 500px

I have been using 500px quite extensively in the past, but I haven't used it in the recent years. I used to be able to export to 500px directly from Lightroom classic, but things seem to have changed: On the [500px support page](https://support.500px.com/hc/en-us/articles/204728107-I-m-having-Lightroom-plugin-problems-) it says that the export plugin has been discontinued.

Now I wonder why that is? That plugin made people use 500px, why would they cut off their customers from their development flow?

And more importantly, is there any alternative plugin that I could use for that purpose? Google did not spit out anything really useful?

Comment: We can't know why they made their business decision to remove the plugin.  And the page you linked to mentions their current upload methodology

Comment: @PeterM, it only mentions the manual upload flow which obviously I cannot use to sync a collection directly from LR. Looking for some plugin that would allow me to use 500px's API to upload images.

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider the usage of 500px so extensively. IMHO reputation of this site drop significantly in last years. Also as sales point if not very popular

Comment: @Aileron79 You need to edit your question to explain what functionality you are now missing.  And have you contacted their support site to ask *them* about how to do things?

Answer (score -1):

Currently, the support of this plugin has been stopped by Lightroom, and nothing can be done for the new versions of Lightroom to use this plugin. For more guidance, [read this link](https://support.500px.com/hc/en-us/articles/204728107-Lightroom-Plugin#:%7E:text=The%20500px%20Lightroom%20plugin%20is,download%20it%20from%20our%20site.)
, because even if you use the old versions of Lightroom to use this plugin, Your account username and password will not be accepted by 500px.com.